# Cannot clone from GitLab in Android Studio via SSH

Tags: android, git, android-studio, ssh

I set up a fresh workstation and having trouble with Android Studio getting access to any GitLab repo via SSH; HTTPS works.

I've tested the public gitlab.com and a local installed one - both working fine with HTTPS but not with SSH.

This happens only in Android Studio. Connecting via command line, TortoiseGit etc. works fine (so I assume the SSH key is correctly bound to by GitLab user).

This also happens only when using GitLab. When trying GitHub (same SSH key), everything works fine.

---

Windows 7 | Git for Windows | SSH key created on ubuntu and copied over | Android Studio Bundle from yesterday